# How do you auto convert one image into three and auto rotate two of them counterclockwise with an image uploader?

Tags: wordpress, image

I don't know if I asked that right. Let me try to explain a little more. First, I have WordPress installed on my site, if that means anything. Using a frontend image uploader, I want to be able to upload one image and, upon submitting, the output would be three images:

1. original photo (less than 130px in width and height)
2. original photo but rotated at 35 degrees counterclockwise
3. original photo but rotated at 45 degrees counterclockwise

I would like these three image outputs automatically called into three designated areas on the page. For example:

Gold Photo Frame #1 (top)
Blue Photo Frame #2 (middle)
Red  Photo Frame #3 (bottom)

Ugh... here... I made an image to illustrate what I am hoping and needing to achieve:

[image: An illustration of what I need: auto image copying and auto rotation using an image uploader]

Is this possible? If so will someone please tell me on how to do this or where a tutorial is on how to do this? What is this process called so I can effectively find the solution or method to doing this? Or is there already a plugin or script that is out there that will let me do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your functions.php use the `add_image_size` function

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
add_image_size( 'upload', 130, 130, true );
```

then in your theme (front-end)

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {?>
<div class="gold-frame uploaded-pic"><?php the_post_thumbnail('upload'); ?></div>
<div class="blue-frame  uploaded-pic"><?php the_post_thumbnail('upload'); ?></div>
<div class="red-frame uploaded-pic"><?php the_post_thumbnail('upload'); ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

CSS

```
.uploaded-pic img{width:130px; height:130px;}
.blue-frame img{transform:rotate(35deg); -ms-transform:rotate(35deg); /* IE 9 */ -webkit-transform:rotate(35deg); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */}
.red-frame img{transform:rotate(45deg); -ms-transform:rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */ -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */}
```

Comment: Thanks, Mark! It's not exactly what I was looking for, but you definitely put me a whole lot closer to what I need. For some reason the .upload-pic wasn't working right. I removed it from the CSS and HTML. Then replaced the CSS .upload-pic w/ gold-frame. I'll have to keep tweaking it because the output was all the same, but I'll figure it out -- thanks to your awesome lead. Also, is there any way to not have to use the post 'Feature Image' to make this work? I am needing an image uploader that is on the front-end so the public can use it -- similar to Imageshack and Tinypic. Can you help?

Comment: Actually I didn't have to make any more tweaks to your code (other than what I specified above). My system shut off and when I powered it back on, the images were rotated. Hm shrugs. I'm happy. Also, I figured out how to use the 'Feature Image' on WordPress 'Edit Post' screen on the frontend of my site (without having to login or create an account), too. While I'm sure others may know a better way to achieve what I initially wanted, I don't. So if anyone wants to know what I did: I used the browser developer tool to find out what it was...

Comment: ...and found this code:    <div id="postimagediv" class="postbox ">
<div class="handlediv" title="Click to toggle"><br></div><h3 class="hndle"><span>Featured Image</span></h3>
<div class="inside"><p class="hide-if-no-js"><a title="Set featured image" href="http://[my site url]/wp-admin/media-upload.php?post_id=1&amp;type=image&amp;TB_iframe=1&amp;width=640&amp;height=265" id="set-post-thumbnail" class="thickbox">Set featured image</a></p></div>
</div>

I copied & pasted it into my theme's index.php where I also placed Mark's code. I'll have to do some CSS to make everything layout right. YAY!

Comment: @Bari awesome - glad you figured it out. if its good please accept the answer. Thanks :)